# jquery random background position

Tags: jquery, var

How should i put this:

```
var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10001)

$('.background').css({backgroundPosition: "0 (numRand)px"});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since `numRand` is a variable, you need to concatenate it using `+`:

```
$('.background').css({backgroundPosition: "0 " + numRand + "px"});
```